# CSS - See what styling bootstrap has applied to element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this footer and a logo that works fine without bootstrap, but bootstrap is just messing it up. I can't find whats wrong, because I don't know what bootstrap applied to the element. I know I can overwrite it, but I need to know what to overwrite. Is there any way of showing the styling bootstrap applied to the element or just disable all bootstrap styling for that element, not knowing what it is? Also, I need the bootstrap for the rest of the site, so I can't remove the link.

Comment: Use DevTools and find the styling?

Comment: In all browsers, you can see this on the `inspector`.

Comment: I know what you feel, bootstrap can be really intrusive.. Use the developper tools to inspect your elements in a browser, and you should see a "style" tab where you have all applied styles listed for the selected element

Comment: So there is no way of making it easy and just disable all bootstrap for element with a simple command?

Comment: Btw, looking in the editor on computed and see what could affect the element worked. Can I make an answer or should you? @LingasamySakthivel

Comment: @UnityLover123 Check out my answer. Was explaining the whole thing.

Comment: No, bootstrap is setting all sorts of CSS rules, not only for classes but also on most html elements. You need to override these styles case by case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the override the governing style rule. Follow these simple ways, you can use Google Chrome to find out the inherited styles:

1. Open the URL in the browser.
   [image: open url]
2. Right click and select inspect on the Inspect.
   [image: inspect]
3. On the right side, click on the computed.
   [image: computed]
4. You will be able to see from where it's inherited.
   [image: inheritance]

In the above example, check out the `font-size` and `font-weight`. There are so many inherits. Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is hierarchical, meaning the styles from the firstly included CSS file gets overwritten with a secondly included file, if both have definitions for the same tag/class/id.

Add bootstrap as the first include CSS in your head of the document and then include your custom CSS files.

This should solve most clashing CSS styles automatically.