# Top bar not at top

Tags: html, css

I have a top bar that has a drop-down and 3 links. If I try to execute it locally, it works without any problems, leaving the top bar at the top without spaces (top, bottom, left and right), as I want it.
The moment I added a PHP code and run it with a server the bar will leave spaces on all sides. Is it a normal problem? how can I resolve it?

```css
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    left:auto;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
<?php 
        session_start();
        $connessione=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("connessione fallita");      
        $selezione_db=mysql_select_db("my_stockmarketsimulator",$connessione) or die ("Non trovo il db");
        $sql="select CodiceUtente,Username FROM `Utenti` where CodiceUtente=".$_SESSION['user'];
        $ris=mysql_query($sql) or die ("Errore nella ricezione dei dati".$_session['user']."cavallo");
        if ($ris && mysql_num_rows($ris) > 0){
                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($ris)){
                    $Utente=$row['Username'];}
                     }
    echo"<button class='dropbtn'>".$Utente."</button>
    <div class='dropdown-content'>
      <a href='#'><i class='fas fa-cog'></i> Modifica impostazioni</a>
      <a href='#'><i class='fas fa-people-carry'></i> Lista Transizioni</a>
      <a href='PHP/Utente/Logout.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-out-alt'></i> Logout</a>
    </div>";
?>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you do the following: 1. Share your rendered HTML and CSS without the PHP component. 2. Show a screenshot and explain what you don't like about it.

Comment: well, Sudhis solution (of course) worked, but only if i added them in-line the <body> tag

Comment: You can actually use an `!important` in the stylesheet! `:D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of default browser added a margin for body tag. You can reset that using below code.

```
body { margin:0;}
```

[image: attached screen shot for refer]

Comment: Thank you so much! worked only if i added it to my tag <body> (inline) had the same instruction in the external css i use but it doesnt seem to work. Good enough! ^^

Comment: @Auticcat Check my answer... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If Sudhi's answer doesn't work, you can try using `!important` next to it. **But, this is not a recommended good practice.**

```css
body {margin: 0 !important;}
```

Only do this, if you aren't able to find the root cause that messes up your style. You can refer my answer on this question: [CSS - See what styling bootstrap has applied to element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50407286)...